# Can asp.net mvc controller methods be considered restful?

Tags: restful-architecture

If I perform all my operations (add item to cart, check out etc) by calls to controller methods that return JSON to my knockout.js presentation layer, can my application be considered restful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.  There is nothing available to respond to HTTP verbs other than GET and POST.  If you want you can use an [ApiController class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)  This is designed as a restful controller.